# Demos, samples and proof-of-concept code in D

Tags: d

I've been looking at the [D programming language](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/) recently and I'm curious if there are any demos, sample applications, or proof-of-concept code written in it. I want some code that demonstrates situations where D is particularly elegant or advantageous.

There's [dsource.org](http://www.dsource.org/) of course, but the projects hosted there are full-on applications. I'm looking for more "documentation-like" examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at the **Articles section** at the website of the [D Programming Language](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/), you will find what you a looking for.

Just for completeness, i have included direct links to some of the articles here:

- [**Memory management** in the D Programming Language](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/1.0/memory.html)
- [**Exception safety** in the D Programming Language](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/1.0/exception-safe.html)
- [**Templates** in the D Programming Language](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/1.0/templates-revisited.html)

While the title of these links seem like articles about the usual boring concepts that all mainstream programming languages adopt, you might get surprised anyways.

I am aware that these articles are not strictly 'demos', but I am fairly certain that they will give you the knowledge you were looking for.

Answer (score 10):

[Rosetta Code: D category](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:D)

Enough for you? :)

Comment: Wow, what a handy site for comparing languages!

Comment: Mostly good but sometimes there is some crappy code that makes the language look bad.

Answer (score 3):

The [tutorials](http://www.dsource.org/projects/tutorials/) project on Dsource is maybe worth a look.

http://www.dsource.org/projects/tutorials/